# PHP dealing with arrays

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 43543534
        )
)
```

I'm trying to get output as `[0] => [43543534]`

I tried `foreach()` but I'm getting string as output

**Update**  How do i find max value now in this?

Comment: Show the code of what you tried.

Comment: Can you please make it more clear? What are you trying to do?

Comment: this is the wrong way to get that value because 0 contains a array value and the key for that value is uid.

Comment: you want to assign the value for that key or only need to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you have only 1 dimensional array `array('0' => 43543534)`, if you have only 'uid' in the second one

```
foreach ($yourArray as $key => $val) {
  echo '['.$key.'] => ['.$val['uid'].']<br />';
}
```

Comment: :How do i find max value now in this?

Comment: $max = 0;$maxKey=0; foreach($yourArray as $key=>$val) { if($val['uid'] > $max) {$max = $val['uid']; $maxKey=$key;} } echo '['.$maxKey.'] => ['.$max.']<br />';

Answer (score 0):

```
$var  = array( '0' => array ( 'uid' => '43543534' ) );

foreach($var as $arr):  
echo $arr['uid'];  
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, but here are two ways to accomplish that using the original array:

```
$array = array( '0' => array ( 'uid' => '43543534' ) );
$result[0] = $array[0]['uid];
```

or with `foreach`

```
$array = array( '0' => array ( 'uid' => '43543534' ) );
foreach($array as $a){
    $result[] = $a['uid'];
}
```