# PHP arrays to find max , min value

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [min and max in multidimensional-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497810/min-and-max-in-multidimensional-array)

How do i find max and min value in this array.Below is the type of array.

```
    Array
    (
       [0] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 43543534
    )
    )
```

Comment: `$min = $max = $array[0]['uid'];`.... please provide a more comprehensive example and use [the search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+min+max+value+array) before you ask a question.

Comment: Your question is not clear, is it a 2-dimensional array? Or do you want to find the max value of [0] index of the array?

Comment: @mahadeb:I've posted my array format itself.What else you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [your previous question and its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8430293/502381), you're going to loop through the array anyway. While you're doing that you can calculate the maximum value:

```
$maxUid = 0;

foreach ($yourArray as $key => $val) {
    $maxUid = max( $maxUid, $val[ 'uid' ] );
    // do everything else
}
```

Comment: :Max array value should be one and min value should be one.Here i get group of value

Answer (score 0):

```
$min = 99999999; //to make sure it's not below all the values
$max = 0;
foreach($array as $a){
    if($max < max($a)) $max = max($a);
    if($min > min($a)) $min = min($a); 
}

echo "min: $min, max: $max";
```

Comment: Just put all the uids into the $array variable (in the format you selected) and run my script.